# What is the difference between Early inliner and IPA inliner in GCC?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, inlining

Reading through GCC code comments and online documentation, it seems there are two types of inliners - Early inliner and the IPA inliner.
For example, in gcc/ipa-fnsummary.c

> /* When optimizing and analyzing for IPA inliner, initialize loop
>   optimizer so we can produce proper inline hints.
>
> When optimizing and analyzing for early inliner, initialize node
>   params so we can produce correct BB predicates.  */

What are these two kinds of inliners ? And What is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put:

- The early inliner operates on the single source file level, when compiling a single file. It will inline functions in the scope of the compiled source file and its included header files only (the scope of a single compilation unit).
- The IPA inliner operates on link time, during whole program optimization. It takes place when activating the `-flto` option, standing for Link Time
  Optimization.

When `-flto` is specified, gcc embeds the intermediate program representation, called a GIMPLE tree, into specialized sections in each object file. Later on, the link time optimizer (GCC's `lto1` executable) reads this information, and executes different optimization passes, including the IPA inliner, to produce the final optimized executable.

The impact of the two inliners could be illustrated with a simple example:

```
// foo.h
void foo() {}

// goo.h
int goo();

// goo.cpp
#include "goo.h"
int goo() { return 0x123; }

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "goo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    return goo();
}
```

First, usual `-O3` compilation:

`g++ -O3 foo.cpp goo.cpp`

By disassembling `a.out` (`objdump a.out -d`) we get the following code for `main`:

```
00000000000004f0 <main>:
 4f0:   e9 0b 01 00 00          jmpq   600 <_Z3goov>
 4f5:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 4fc:   00 00 00 
 4ff:   90                      nop
```

The call to `foo()` is gone - this is the work of the early inliner. The function `goo()`, however, is not visible to the compiler during compilation of `foo.cpp`, so it is not able to optimize it.

Now, repeating compilation with `-flto`:

`g++ -O3 -flto foo.cpp goo.cpp`

We would get the following disassembly:

```
00000000000004f0 <main>:
 4f0:   b8 23 01 00 00          mov    $0x123,%eax
 4f5:   c3                      retq   
 4f6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 4fd:   00 00 00
```

This time, the call to `goo` was inlined and replaced with its result, `0x123` - this is the work of the IPA inliner.

Comment: IPA inline is independent of LTO, it happens even without LTO. You can get _more_ IPA inlining with LTO, because the compiler can see across modules. But it still works without LTO (just only within a single translation unit).

Answer (score 1):

According to the internal documentation in the ipa-inline.c early inline is a simple local inlining pass that inline callees in the current function based on local properties only. The main strength of this pass is its ability to remove the abstraction penalty present in most C++ code and prepare the code for the more advanced inter-procedural analysis (IPA).

The IPA inliner is a more advanced inliner based on the information collected during IPA. Since it has more information it can make a better estimate on which callees are most beneficial to inline. It will also prune the call-graph and remove functions where all the call sites have been inlined.

For more information refer to the internal documentation of [ipa-inline.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ipa-inline.c)